DJANGO pythonAnywhere Deployment
I am trying to deploy a simple Django application (Tic-Tac-Toe), but I'm having a hard time. When reloading and trying to deploy my Django application via PythonAnywhere, these errors pop up in the error console related to my WSGI file. I'm confused as to why I'm getting the error:
"TicTacToe" module not defined

This occurs even though I am not explicitly calling the TicTacToe module anywhere in my code. Below are links to pictures of the errors and the current code in my WSGI file:

Console Errors While Migrating with Bash
Code and Directory Structure
Web Error Screenshot

I have applied necessary changes to my settings.py and wsgi.py files, but it seems to be catching an old error. I believe the relative path locations are properly defined, but I'm not sure what's causing these issues and preventing my app from deploying.
Any help or guidance on what might be going wrong would be greatly appreciated!

Please read Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors? You can [edit] your question and replace the images with [code block]s. The easiest way to do this is to paste the code as text directly into your question, then select it and click the code block button.
